# How do I make a phone number a clickable link in the Trello iOS app?

Tags: trello, mobile, markdown

Is there a way to do Markdown in Trello so that if you click the phone number on a card on the iPhone it will actually call the number?

I just realized that you can use Markdown in order to make URLs and email addresses clickable on the mobile web version of Trello and wondering if that extends to phone numbers.

I tried `<tel:333-3333-3333>` and similar variations, and none worked for me.

Comment: We'll make sure this is filed as a feature request for the iPhone app.

Comment: This might be deemed off-topic by the webapps community. Don't worry if it gets closed. We've noted this feedback.

Comment: This type of question, about how to use what might be a feature that just needs a heads-up on, is fine for the site. If it was a feature request or reporting a bug, then we'd be out of scope @ric

Answer (score 1):

If you use the app Contacts+ you can share the contact to create a Trello card and it will make the phone numbers and emails linkable in Trello

Answer (score 1):

You can use Markdown syntax for links format as `[link text](link_href)` to make it work.
In the description of the card you can make link like this `[clickable word](tel:1234567890)` so the words 'clickable word' will be linked to the phone and will enable you to make a phone call from a Trello card.

Comment: This works really well for me, both in Android and WebApp, not sure how iOS app works. Code is `(text to displasy)[tel:12345551234]`

Comment: @JayWick Your suggestion is great, but not exact. All have to be done is to swap the type of parentheses. Example: `[text to displasy](tel:12345551234)`

Comment: Whoops that's it!